# Fitting regression line to timeseries data in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, lm

I have a monthly data set `test` that when plotted, looks like this:

[image]

My objective is to fit a regression line to the data and create a forecast of future months (to start with, 6 months).  I have consulted [this reference](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/8) which implements the `forecast` package.

However, when I run `tslm()`,  I get the following errors:

```
tslm(test$Freq)
Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```

And also when I attempt to convert `test` to a timeseries object, I get another error.

```
as.Date(as.character(test$Month))
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Any suggestions on how to properly implement the `tslm()` function on the given data set would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the data sample:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(Month = structure(1:31, .Label = c("2014-11", 
"2014-12", "2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", 
"2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", 
"2015-12", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", 
"2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", 
"2016-12", "2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03", "2017-04", "2017-05"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(3L, 15L, 863L, 1031L, 4242L, 11610L, 
20605L, 21105L, 29533L, 27354L, 30573L, 24423L, 20216L, 13616L, 
9674L, 10037L, 13959L, 18760L, 28121L, 34346L, 36099L, 35841L, 
39318L, 30736L, 27517L, 12588L, 13599L, 14465L, 17142L, 26229L, 
29484L)), .Names = c("Month", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -31L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: on a side note ... test$Month <- as.Date(paste0(as.character(test$Month), "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: Study R class definitions. Those are NOT valid R dates. If you insist on using months, then consider the yearmon class in pkg:zoo. You should also search on modeling data with strong seasonal dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test2 <- ts(test$Freq, start= c(2014, 11), frequency = 12)
fit <- tslm(test2 ~ trend + season)
plot(forecast(fit, h=20))
```

Comment: thanks but what do the x-axis tick marks represent? it is unclear and why does `start` contain two variables which are not years?

Comment: @the_darkside if you plot it with start = c(2014, 11) the axis is correct, and self explanatory.